# Interaction of polarized beam to optical active substance

Tags: optics, angular-momentum, polarization

Kostyas question for angular momentum and half wave plates 
[Half wave plate and angular momentum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4479/half-wave-plate-and-angular-momentum)
made me think a little bit. It took me some seconds to "swallow" the answer. :=)

Then I started to think further, whether such a plate, rotating in the 
right direction, could lead to a slightly shorter wavelength?

And further, what happens in an optical active substance, which 
"rotates" the plane of polarisation of a light beam? 
Of course no momentum is changed, there is only a extremely small 
difference of interaction of the two circular polarized waves 
(representing the plane polarized beam) with the substance. 
Is there any "mechanic" reaction of the "sample"? 
Might a small torque be excerted along the axis parallel to the 
direction of the beam?

Comment: I believe this goes in the field of "optical tweezers". People are being very active in using light to directly act in mechanical ways on small objects (proteins, nanoparticles, etc.)

Comment: Could you link to the question of Kostya's that you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About wavelength change: In general, if you have light at frequency $f_1$ and it's modulated (in any way for any reason) at frequency $f_2$, you'll get sidebands of light at frequencies $f_1+f_2$ and $f_1-f_2$.

So yes, if you spin a half-wave plate at a constant speed, the light traveling through it will acquire sidebands at a shifted frequency and wavelength.